# Matrix completion with proximal gradient method

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus

I am trying to solve the matrix completion problem with proximal gradient method: $$\min_{||X||_* \leq \theta} \frac{1}{2}\sum_{(i, j) \in \Omega} (X_{ij} - M_{ij})^2$$ or in terms of the projection operator: $$\min_{||X||_* \leq \theta} \frac{1}{2} ||P_\Omega(X) - P_\Omega(M)||_F^2$$

Now, I know how to solve $$\min_{\Vert X\Vert_* \leq \theta} \frac{1}{2} \Vert X-Y\Vert_F^2$$ since that is just $X = U D^* V^\top$ where $Y = UDV^\top$ and $D^* = \operatorname{diag}(d^*)$ and $D = \operatorname{diag}(d)$ where $d^*$ is the solution to $$\min_{\Vert x\Vert_1 \leq \theta} \Vert x-d\Vert^2$$. Can someone point in the right direction on how to apply this to solve the matrix completion problem using proximal gradient method?